# Generate pairs with List using c#

Tags: c#, linq, generic-collections

Basically i have list of rooms from hotel, 
Lets say user selects 3 rooms with

1st room with 2 adults,
 
2nd with 4 adults
3rd with 6 adults.

fine, When i send this request to XML service. it gives me rooms with unpair list so I need to pair
these rooms on base of Hotel Room Type which is RO (ROOM ONLY), 
Each pair elements should have same ROOM TYPE but with every requested room as described above.

So I think you have now clear image what is going on :), Second value in Occupancy property shows here Number of Adults.
I am not good in maths but I think that its some kind of SETS in Math.

In result we have total 4 Rooms, In which we have first 2 Rooms for 2 Adults (//1 and //2) So we have to pair these rooms with other (4 adults an 6 adults) rooms.

Now in this scenario I need 3 pairs as described below

> SB, Room Only, 1,2  **for 2 Adults**
>   SB, Room Only, 1,4  **for 4 Adults**
>   SB, Room Only, 1,6  **for 6 Adults**
>   
>   DQ, Room Only, 1,2  **for 2 Adults**
>   SB, Room Only, 1,4  **for 4 Adults**
>   SB, Room Only, 1,6  **for 6 Adults**
>
> SB, Breakfast, 1,2   **for 2 Adults**
>   SB, Breakfast, 1,4   **for 4 Adults**
>   SB, Breakfast, 1,6   **for 6 Adults**

```
public class rr {
   public string roomType { get; set; }
   public string room { get; set; }
   public string occupancy { get; set; }        
}

List<rr> listOfOccupancy = new List<rr>();

listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Room Only", occupancy = "1,2" }); //1
listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "DQ", room = "Room Only", occupancy = "1,2" }); //2
listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Room Only", occupancy = "1,4" }); //3
listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Room Only", occupancy = "1,6" }); //4 

listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Breakfast", occupancy = "1,2" }); //5
listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Breakfast", occupancy = "1,4" }); //6
listOfOccupancy.Add(new rr { roomType = "SB", room = "Breakfast", occupancy = "1,6" }); //7
```

Comment: how about using a struct? or string?

Comment: it is unclear why the pairs are duplicated in your example. Can you perhaps expand on what rules you expect it to follow? i.e. *why* are there 12 outputs from these 8 inputs?

Comment: Hello @MarcGravell sorry for my last unclear question. Now i think you can understand what i need.

Comment: It didn't make the question more clear...

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't explain why you get those particular 6 rows from the 4 inputs. Please talk us through why you expect those results, and I reckon we can come up with what you are after. Right now: it is not clear.

Comment: This is not a clear question, you need to provide more examples, preferably with more sensible data structures. What is the point of the `room` property if it is always the same? What does the `occupancy` property indicate - if it indicates two numbers, why is it stored as a single `string`?

Comment: @MarcGravell, Now I have described in more detail. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @Muhammad why are "SB, Room Only, 1,4 for 4 Adults" and
"SB, Room Only, 1,6 for 6 Adults" duplicated?

Comment: @MarcGravell No its not duplicated, basically there is other attributes which i am not showing here. e.g price. Price is different for 6 adults.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanSaleem then I restate: I can see the input, and I can see the output; what I can't see is what reasoning you are wanting to follow, to get that particular output from that input. Rather than just showing us the "in" and "out"... please add the *why*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this may point you in the right direction:

```
    var x = listOfOccupancy
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.room)
        .ThenBy(r => r.occupancy)
        // Optional distinct using equality comparer
        //.Distinct(...)
        .ToList();
```

Cheers, Alex

EDIT: This produces:

```
RO, 1,2
RO, 1,2
RO, 1,4
RO, 1,6
AB, 1,2
AB, 1,2
AB, 1,4
AB, 1,6
```

Comment: Don't think it is what author wants.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to de-dupe the list, and then double it. See the code below:

```
var distinctList = listOfOccupancy.Select(l => new { l.room, l.occupancy }).Distinct();
var doubledList = distinctList.Concat(distinctList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, which looks a bit complicated, but does what you want:

```
var results = listOfOccupancy.GroupBy(rr => rr.room)
                             .Select(g => g.GroupBy(rr => rr.occupancy).SelectMany(g2 => g2.Select((rr, i) => new { rr, i })))
                             .SelectMany(g => g.Select(g2 => g2))
                             .OrderBy(e => e.rr.room)
                             .ThenBy(e => e.i)
                             .ThenBy(e => e.rr.occupancy)
                             .Select(e => e.rr)
                             .ToList();
```

What it does? First of all, it group input list by `room` property value. For every group it groups again by `occupancy` and assigns an index for element within every subgroup. After that all groups are flatted using `SelectMany`. On that point we have a list of anonymous object with `room`, `occupancy` and `index`. After proper sorting you have your data in correct order.

Result is a list with following order:

```
AB 1,2
AB 1,4
AB 1,6
AB 1,2
RO 1,2
RO 1,4
RO 1,6
RO 1,2
```